# Sentence construction using come or came

Tags: sentence-construction

I saw my boss coming to office. I started conversation.

"Hi sir GM, You Just came/come to office?"

Which one is appropriate to use came or come?

Is verb *just* is used as linking verb ?

Answer (score 1):

"Came" since this is past tense.  But to make a question you need to use question form:

> Did you just come to the office?

But you are doing this all wrong!  You can ask someone a question if you don't know the answer.

You can ask someone a question like "how are you?" which expects the answer "I'm fine" to begin a conversation.

You can rhetorically ask a question to engage people with the implied answer

But in your case  "Sir, did you just come to the office?" is a weird question to ask!  Try saying "Sir, It's good to see you. ...."

Don't use "Sir" as a title, unless the person has been knighted. "Hello Sir" is possible in some cultures, but would be very odd in England.  "Hello Mr Martin" or "Hello Graeme" would be a much more normal way to speak to your boss (assuming his name is Graeme Martin).

The word "just" is an adverb, which means "very recently". It's not a linking verb.

Answer (score 0):

> "Hi sir GM, You Just came/come to office?"

Since GM has already arrived, use the past tense "came" in this instance.

The word "just" in this sentence is an adverb modifying the verb "came".  The word "just" can be a noun, but not a verb.